# Custom routing for Gatsby function handler declared inside `api` folder

Tags: gatsby

I am new to using Gatsby and using Gatsby v5.11.0. I have developed a site. I also have added 4 function handlers inside api folder which is working fine.

However, I have two issues for which I was not able to find any reference in gatsby website or in stack overflow. Any reference would be greatly appreciated.

1. I don't want to use file based routing for these function handlers. Instead wanted to use a custom path.
2. I wanted to have these api's accessible only from a sub domain and not from root domain.

Here is an example of what I have currently.

My project structure:

```
-- src
 |-- pages
   |-- page1.js
   |-- page2.js
 |-- api
   |-- handler1.js
   |-- handler2.js
   |-- handler3.js
   |-- handler4.js
```

With above folder structure I was able to access the pages and handlers using following url

```
https://www.my-domain-name.com/page1
https://www.my-domain-name.com/page2
https://www.my-domain-name.com/api/handler1
https://www.my-domain-name.com/api/handler2
```

While it is fine for pages, for api I wanted it to access with custom domain and custom path like in following example.

```
https://www.my-domain-name.com/page1
https://www.my-domain-name.com/page2
https://api.my-domain-name.com/some/other/path/for/handler1
https://api.my-domain-name.com/some/different/path/for/handler2
```

I tried to use actions.createRedirect inside gatsby-node.js file and it does not work for api handlers. I don't see any reference on how to handle such cases for api's.

I know I can achieve this by creating a similar folder structure and export the handler from there. But I did not like the idea of creating such deep nested folder just to hold single file.